# How to open a door without a door knob?

Tags: doors, lock

I am currently locked inside of the apartment that I just moved into today. I noticed that the door knob was a bit loose when I first opened the door this morning and when I turned the knob from the outside, the knob wouldn’t turn on the inside.

Eventually I tried to leave my apt and as I turned the knob and pulled, I just pulled out the knob. Anyone know how I can open this knobless door?

All other tutorials and forums on the internet seem to be for a different type of door. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance. This is the best picture I could take because the opening is so small and the camera would not focus properly on any shot at all more detailed.

[image: best picture I could take since the opening is small and I couldn’t get the camera to focus well on any shot at all more detailed.]

Comment: Do you (did you) have the half of the doorknob with the rod? If so, stick it back in and turn as you do not need the knob on the other side to open the door.

Answer (score 3):

Stick a slotted screwdriver into the square hole and turn it counterclockwise...

Comment: If it is the old lock that think it is, it is not really a lock, but a latchset and turning it either way will get it open. But the slotted (flat) screwdriver is the trick.

Comment: Good point about turning it either way.

Comment: JaCk is right.....

Comment: Call your landlord or 911.

Comment: Please use your local non-emergency police line if you need non-emergency police assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a kitchen knife will work, if you do not have any screwdrivers in your apt by sticking the pointed end in the square hole and turning the mechanism.

Comment: ... work how? (A bit more detail would help the OP.)